# How to stop foreach to repeat content?

Tags: php

I don't know PHP, so this might be a very basic question. I apologize in advance.

I'm working on a page that has a list of products and for each product, there is an option to delete it. The backend dev made it so it works great. However, they're not available at the moment and the client wants a modal that checks with the user if they're sure they want to delete a product before the action is complete.

I've included a modal. And just moved the delete action to the modal's 'Yes' button. However, because we have several products listed, it keeps repeating the button over and over. I realize this might be a basic fix, but I have no idea what I'm doing. Can someone please just take a look? Thank you!

Here's the (edited - I moved the action to the modal in this version) code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="quotes">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="pages-header text-right">
                <a href="{{route('product.create')}}" class="btn btn-success new-quote-button">New Product</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card rounded-0 border-0 active-products">
                <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <h3 class="mb-0">Products</h3>
                </div>
                <table class="table text-center" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col" class="text-left quote-name">Name</th>
                            <th scope="col">Category</th>
                            <th scope="col">Hardware Price</th>
                            <th scope="col">Yearly License Cost</th>
                            <th scope="col">Monthly License Cost</th>
                            <th scope="col">Type</th>
                            <th scope="col" colspan="2"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach($products as $product)
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col" class="quote-name">
                                {{$product->name}}
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col">
                                {{$product->category}}
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col">
                                {{$product->hardware_price}}
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col">
                                {{$product->yearly_license_cost}}
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col">
                                {{$product->monthly_license_cost}}
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col">
                                {{$product->type}}
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="actions-col">
                                <a href="{{route('product.edit', $product->id)}}" class="text-primary">Edit</a>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="actions-col">
                                <a href="#" class="text-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal">Delete</a>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                {{ $products->links() }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    @foreach($products as $product)
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                    <form method="POST" action="{{route('product.destroy', $product)}}" id="delete-{{$product->id}}">
                        @csrf
                        @method('DELETE')

                        <a href="#" class="text-danger">Delete</a>
                    </form>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I tweak this?

Comment: This is no PHP. What Framework are you using?

Comment: The file extension says .php. I believe it's Laravel.

Comment: @MarkusZeller its laravel Framework

Comment: You can keep the modal inside the foreach loop. Just add product id to both target modal id and also the modal id.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pass data attr in delete button and append into modal form using js script.

**Change into HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="text-danger deleteproduct" data-id="{{$product->id}}" data-product="{{$product}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal">Delete</a>
```

**Add JS Script**

```
 $(document).on('click', '.deleteproduct', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var product = $(this).attr('data-product');
        $('#Deletefrm').attr('id','delete-'+id);
        $('#Deletefrm').attr('action','/product.destroy/'+product);
    });

 $('#deleteModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
        $('#Deletefrm').attr('id','');
        $('#Deletefrm').attr('action','');
    });
```

**Change in Modal**

```
<div class="modal-footer">

 <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                <form method="POST" id="Deletefrm" action="" id="">
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')

                    <a href="#" class="text-danger">Delete</a>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="quotes">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="pages-header text-right">
                <a href="{{route('product.create')}}" class="btn btn-success new-quote-button">New Product</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card rounded-0 border-0 active-products">
                <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <h3 class="mb-0">Products</h3>
                </div>
                <table class="table text-center" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" class="text-left quote-name">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Category</th>
                        <th scope="col">Hardware Price</th>
                        <th scope="col">Yearly License Cost</th>
                        <th scope="col">Monthly License Cost</th>
                        <th scope="col">Type</th>
                        <th scope="col" colspan="2"></th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    @foreach($products as $product)
                        <tr>
                            <td scope="col" class="quote-name">
                                {{$product->name}}
                            </td>
                            <td scope="col">
                                {{$product->category}}
                            </td>
                            <td scope="col">
                                {{$product->hardware_price}}
                            </td>
                            <td scope="col">
                                {{$product->yearly_license_cost}}
                            </td>
                            <td scope="col">
                                {{$product->monthly_license_cost}}
                            </td>
                            <td scope="col">
                                {{$product->type}}
                            </td>
                            <td scope="col" class="actions-col">
                                <a href="{{route('product.edit', $product->id)}}" class="text-primary">Edit</a>
                            </td>
                            <td scope="col" class="actions-col">
                                <a href="#" class="text-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal-{{$product->id}}">Delete</a>

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal-{{$product->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModalLabel-{{$product->id}}" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteModalLabel-{{$product->id}}">Modal title</h5>
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                ...
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                @foreach($products as $product)
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                                                    <form method="POST" action="{{route('product.destroy', $product)}}" id="delete-{{$product->id}}">
                                                        @csrf
                                                        @method('DELETE')

                                                        <a href="#" class="text-danger">Delete</a>
                                                    </form>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                {{ $products->links() }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal -->

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This doesn't solve it though. It still keeps repeating.

Comment: You have to hide the modals in each row. Only when the delete button is clicked in its handler you have to show the modal so that action can be taken on that modal.